# Unable to get text from toasted message in selenium java

Tags: java, string, selenium

I am new to selenium(java), I was able to inspect element for Toasted message but not sure how to get text and validate the case.
Scenario :
1.Click on sign in button
2.Toasted message is appeared for 10 seconds.
3.Should capture the toasted message and validate text.

Can any one help me in this.

Comment: we need more than the scenario to help... Please provide the HTML and your code trials...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, wait for Toasted message

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 80);
element=wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(locator)));
```

Get the text from toasted message

```
String actualText =driver.findElement(By.xpath("YourXpath")).getText();
```

Mention the text you are expcting:

```
String expectedText = "Your Text"
```

Finally, compare actual with expected:

```
Assert.assertEquals(actualText, expectedText);
```

Let me know if you need any other help.

Comment: Every thing is perfect but may I know what should be passed instead of "locator" - 2nd line. As I added locator = toasted message xpath and in "your xpath" also added same xpath.
how can i check acutalText = ExpectedText.

Comment: In locator basically you need to pass Xpath of the Toasted text . In your text mention the text you are looking for.Then the assert condition is already in place which will compare actualText= ExpectedText. Hope that's what you are looking for.